# placing image as div background

Tags: html, image

How can I place only an image in a div as background image, and add url link to it.
Currenty I'm doing it this way:

```
<div class="image"><a href="example.com"><img src="books.png" alt="Test" /></a></div>
```

I want to do something like following, but its not working (the image does not appear).

```
<div class="image"><a href="example.com"><span class="books"></span></a></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What CSS are you using for your image and books classes?

Comment: If you want an image to be a link, then you need to tell the person looking at the page where the link is going. This requires **content**. If you want to use an image as this content, use an `<img>` element. A background is inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the background image in the `<a>` tag if you want it clickable.

your css:

```
.image a { display: block;
    background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 50px; /* obviously use the same dimensions as your image */
    width: 50px; /* obviously use the same dimensions as your image */
}


<div class="image"><a href="example.com">&nbsp;</a></div>
```

or better yet, get rid of the div entirely, and just apply the `image` class directly to a:

```
<a class="image" href="example.com">&nbsp;</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely it's because the div is empty. Try something like:

```
<div class="image"><a href="example.com"><span class="books">&nbsp;</span></a></div>
```

If it's still not showing, set the "image" class to have a background color too, so that you can see how big the div 'thinks' it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an image to be in the background you need to set, the style property "z-index:-1", that way, the image will be in the back of the other elements in the same content div

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a DIV?

I am writing the style inside you can use it in css file

```
<a class="image" style="display:block; width: (image-width); height: (image-height); background: url(image-link)"></a>
```

this will work...

you can use it like this if you need div..

```
<div class="image" style="width: (image-width); height: (image-height); background: url(image-link)"><a href=""  style="display:block;"></a></div>
```